# Return only funded fields in response(Django Rest SearchFilter)

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have `ViewSet` which have `SearchFilter` in `filter_backends` and two search_fields. How to return JSON represents the only field results?
For example if i send response for search with "jo" substring i will have only one field for this search(funded user name or full name), not both user name and email in each JSON object:

```
{
    [{
        "username": "jonh";
     },
     {
        "fullname": "Jonh";
     },
     {
        "username": "jo";
     },
     {
        "fullname": "Johnson";
     }
    ]
}
```

viewsets.py:

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsUserOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('^username', '^fullname',)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'action') and self.action == 'list':
            return UserListSerializer
        return UserDetailSerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'fullname')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Serializer factory function that takes the search params as an an argument:

```
def generate_user_list_serializer(search_terms):

    class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = tuple(search_terms)

    return UserListSerializer
```

Then in your view, have the serializer generated on the fly:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):

    # make sure that the fields are available
    validated_params = [p for p in self.query_params if p in Myfields]

    return generate_user_list_serializer(self.query_params)
```